# Creating and connecting to a new AWS RDS SQL Server instance

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services

I cannot create a simple new SQL Server RDS instance and connect to it. I've provided screenshots of the configurations I have used below:

[RDS MS SQL Server Configuration Step 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIzLI.png)

[Security Group Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Avd.png)

[DB Instance Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZX4Nh.png)

[Error when attempting to connect via SSMS 2017 without port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YNqI.png)

[Error when attempting to connect via SSMS 2017 with port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLn1F.png)

From the above as I understand it my security group is set up correctly (My IP should be able to connect via SQL Server authentication via port 1433). Without providing a port in SSMS 2017 I get a "Named Pipes Provider" error and when I do provide the 1433 port (`testdb.cjkirvd4vbhk.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433`) I get a timeout error. What am I doing wrong? I just want to be able to create a SQL Server RDS instance and connect to it.

Comment: my ip and your ip is same ? make sure it has not changed ? moreover are you able to connect it when traffic from everywhere is allowed ?

Comment: Can you update the SG to 0.0.0.0/0 and validate its working? - What about using port 3306?

Comment: @jarnohenneman I've tried traffic from anywhere (0.0.0.0/0) and using port 3306 and I still cannot connect using SSMS.

Comment: Click on the options button in your "Connect to Server" dialog. What do you have selected for "Network protocol"? This should be TCP/IP.